# How Can I add A call back to a module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I create this small module to import in other node js modules.
However my callback function is giving me an error. "callback is not a function".

How can I make it work.

```
exports.saveConnection = function dao(action, callback){

    pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callback(''); 
        }

        //create tables
        var createTables = function(conn){
            conn.release();
            var rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream('struct.sql'),
                terminal: false
            });
            rl.on('line', function(chunk){
                conn.query(chunk.toString('ascii'), function(err, sets, fields){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Table created");
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log("Table created");
        }

        var findByPrimaryKey = conn.query("select * from user",function(err,rows){
            conn.release();
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }          
        });

        conn.on('error', function(err) {      
            console.log(err);
            return;    
        });
        callback(findByPrimaryKey);
    });
};
```

Comment: how you are calling saveConnection?

Answer (score 1):

When ever you are about to call callback you have to check if its a function or not. you can do that by following check

```
if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
    // call callback here
} else {
   // just return because callback is not supplied
 }
```

and when you call `exports.saveConnection` you have to supply callback as second param if you want to do something in that callback